# ValueToCompare property cannot be converted to type 'Date' Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have a compare validator linked to a textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Birthdate" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="Date"/>

<asp:CompareValidator ID="cmpBDate" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Must be at least 20 years old" 
ControlToValidate="Birthdate" Type="Date" ValueToCompare="<%# DateTime.Today.AddYears(-20).ToShortDateString() %>" 
Operator="LessThan" CssClass="text-danger"  Display="Dynamic">
</asp:CompareValidator>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
 Page.DataBind();
}
```

But I get an error:

> The value "" of the ValueToCompare property of 'cmpBDate' cannot be
>   converted to type 'Date'.

With a stack trace of:

```
[HttpException (0x80004005): The value '08-Oct-97' of the ValueToCompare property of 'cmpBDate' cannot be converted to type 'Date'.]
System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompareValidator.ControlPropertiesValid() +2619109
System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseValidator.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +37
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +88
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean 
includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint,Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +985
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to format the Date according to what is known serverside. My guess something along `2917-10-08` should work. Maybe the roundtrip variant will work.

- [Custom DateTime Formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)
- [Default DateTime Formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings)